# What is an $f(x,c)$ that gets very big very fast as $x$ moves away from $c$ in $[0,1]$?

Tags: functions

I want a function such that, say if $c = .3$, the graph of $f(x,.3)$ looks like this:

[image: minimum at c=.3]

That is actually a graph of $f(x,c) = -\frac{(x - c)^2}{(1-x)x}$

But this function increases too slowly and is too flat around the minimum, $x=c$.
What is a function that is steeper around the minimum and much steeper as you move away from it? That is, one that moves quickly to 100, 1000, etc.

Comment: Maybe you need a function that has a big positive second derivative around 0.3.

Comment: Do you need $f(x,c) \to \infty$ as $x \to 0^+$ and $x \to 1^-$?

Comment: No, I guess it doesn't need to asymptote, but that seems important for it to have exceedingly high derivatives for values in the interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like $f(x,c) = e^{\tfrac{\alpha(x-c)^2}{x(1-x)}}$ for some big number $\alpha > 0$ satisfy your conditions?

Comment: Hmm I may be doing something wrong, but it looks like larger values of $\alpha$ make it flatter?

Comment: Increasing $\alpha$ will make $f(x,c)$ increase faster as $x \to 0^+$ and $x \to 1^-$. What probably is happening is your plotting software is changing the vertical axis scale as you increase $\alpha$, which makes the graph look flatter.